# Get meta-data from manifest in UnitTest

Tags: android, testing, android-testing

I'm currently running into trouble retrieving `<meta-data>` tags from my AndroidManifest file while being inside an InstrumentationTest.

I am using a library ([Sugar ORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/index.html)) which stores some essential information inside these tags. As soon as I use the library inside the code to be tested I run into problems.

```
AndroidManifest.xml

<manifest package="org.something" ...>
    ...
    <application ...>
        <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="foo.db" />
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Retrieval of the metadata works like that:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
try {
    ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    value = ai.metaData.getString(name);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("sugar", "Couldn't find config value: " + name);
}
```

The test is running as a `InstrumentationTestCase` and sets up the context to be `getInstrumentation().getContext()`.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are running into? You have just desired what you are doing.

Comment: I circumvented the problem for now by not using SugarORM anymore. The problem was that the library could not load its metadata from the manifest file. So the given code throws an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `InstrumentationTestCase` does not contain the meta data from your application.  All you need to do is extend `ApplicationTestCase<Application>` for your test case class.

You can call getContext() in your test cases and that will have the appropriate information in there.

```
PackageManager pm = getContext().getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(getContext().getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

Comment: I think that could do the trick. Unfortunately you will be loading the whole application if you subclass ApplicationTestCase which is very time consuming. I think there is just no way of retrieving the metadata fields during the test run without jumping through hoops. I guess the recommendation for library developers would be to avoid this construct to allow testing in client applications. I will still accept this answer as this might be the only way to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is quite old, however if anyone else is interested, I had this same problem I fixed it by moving the meta-data fields into the application.

So this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
package="com.percolate.coffee"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="coffee.db" />
<meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="2" />
<meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
<meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.percolate" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="com.orm.SugarApp">
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.CoffeeTypeListViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".activity.CoffeeTypeDetailedViewAcitivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_coffee_type_detailed_view_acitivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.CoffeeTypeListViewActivity">

    </activity>
    <!-- SERVICES -->
    <service
        android:name="com.octo.android.robospice.Jackson2SpringAndroidSpiceService"
        android:exported="false"/>
    <service
        android:name="com.octo.android.robospice.spicelist.okhttp.OkHttpBitmapSpiceService"
        android:exported="false"/>

</application>
```

becomes this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
package="com.percolate.coffee"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="coffee.db" />
<meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="2" />
<meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
<meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.percolate" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="com.orm.SugarApp">
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.CoffeeTypeListViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".activity.CoffeeTypeDetailedViewAcitivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_coffee_type_detailed_view_acitivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.CoffeeTypeListViewActivity">

    </activity>
    <!-- SERVICES -->
    <service
        android:name="com.octo.android.robospice.Jackson2SpringAndroidSpiceService"
        android:exported="false"/>
    <service
        android:name="com.octo.android.robospice.spicelist.okhttp.OkHttpBitmapSpiceService"
        android:exported="false"/>

</application>
```

Comment: I think there was a copy paste error. It probably should contain the meta-data fields in the <application .. tag.